# Null value with sum aggregate?

Tags: sql, null, sum

A query performs a sum aggregate over a single column of a table with 10 tuples. If exactly one of tuples has a NULL value on that column, which of the following will happen?

1. The query will return NULL.
2. The query will return the sum of the remaining 9 values.
3. The query will throw an exception.

Would this be 3?

Comment: query will return null. If  you need to add a default value, use coalesce functions

Comment: Is this a homework/quiz question?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: "If one or more null values are eliminated, then a completion condition
is raised: _warning — null value eliminated in set function_."
ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E)

Comment: @Gonzalo. The query **will not** return null... See the horse's answer.

Comment: you're right, I read it very quickly and miss the "aggregate" part. I thought it was a regular select. My bad

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions ignore null values. That's how their behaviour is defined.

So the answer to your question is: 2)

You can easily test that yourself:

```
create table test_null(value integer);
insert into test_null
values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(null);

select sum(value)
from test_null;
```

Returns

```
sum
---
  9
```

---

The "ignoring" part is more obvious when you use the `avg()` aggregate function. The result for the above test data is 1, not 0.9 as one might think. That's because aggregates ignore the rows with null values and therefor the average is computed as 9/9.

```
select avg(value)
from test_null;
```

is equivalent to:

```
select avg(value)
from test_null
WHERE value IS NOT NULL;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/QQREJS70393